# Trying to deploy or release a WPF application in Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

How would I go about releasing or deploying (do those mean the same thing?) my WPF application (.Net Framework 4.7.2) through Azure Pipelines?

I'm a little confused on what to use. There's all these terminologies like artifacts, release, publish, staging. I'm not sure what task I need to use.

Comment: Does you app target .NET Framework or .NET Core? You might have to use the Visual Studio build or MSBuild Task for .NET Framework

Comment: How did you deploy a WPF Application locally? You could get started of Azure Pipelines from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over a typical scenario so you best understand the terminology. This, of course, is just an example.

You have multiple git repositories in Azure DevOps Repos. One of those git repositories is a common library which is shared across multiple projects in your company. Another one is the companies flagship application, written in WPF, and used internally by 100 employees. Lastly, there is a web portal for external clients to submit orders. Each of these git repositories has branch policies in place to prevent checking in directly to the master branch (a pull request is required).

Development Team A works on the core functionality of your technology team, they update the common libraries. As part of the build pipeline, the library is compiled and a NuGet package is generated. The pipeline then publishes the package to your private Azure DevOps Artifacts feed, so that the other development teams can use the package.

Development Team B works on the flagship WPF application. As part of the build pipeline, the pipeline compiles the application. It creates a build artifact of the bin directory. Another stage in the pipeline takes uses the artifact and publishes it to the test environment, and sets a flag on the database that the current test version is the version that was just published. When the development team launches the test application, it is automatically updated because the version was incremented in the database.

Development Team C works on the web application. As part of the build pipeline, the pipeline compiles the application. It deploys the web application to the test web server. The test web application is available immediately for the development team to test.

At a later time, when the iteration cycle is completed, there is a code freeze. The code freeze involves the DevOps team manually running the build pipelines. Because the pipelines were manually run, the first pipeline will deploy the WPF application to the staging environment, and the version number is incremented in the database. The second pipeline deploys the web application to a green-blue server.

The development teams do a final round of testing to ensure there are no bugs which cause a stoppage. Once they are good to go, the WPF application is released from the staging environment by having it pushed out to all of the employee desktops. The release process for the web application involves flipping a switch so that the green server (updated web application) goes live, the network switch points to the green server, then the blue server (older web application) goes down.

If any major issues arise, things can be rolled back by flipping the network switch from the green server back to the blue, and deploying the older version of the WPF application to the employee desktops, etc.

This is just an example, it is not the only way to do this of course.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. What Azure task would I use to get WpfApp1 application out of its bin and to a drop location?

Comment: I understand this better today than I did a year ago. We don't have a blue-green deployment setup. I wish we did. And due to other project priorities, I've had little time to work on the app that I discussed a year ago. Currently I've got the build pipeline signing the app. I created an empty Azure App Service to publish the ClickOnce deployment to. I tried specifying the App Service URL in VS 2019's Publish Wizard, but that doesn't allow me to do that. Now that I'm back on this project, I'm still struggling. Thanks @myermian for your explanation.